# How many sensors can I interface with an Arduino Uno R3?

Tags: arduino, sensor, raspberry-pi, arduino-uno

I got my final project to make, and I have a couple of questions regarding the Arduino Uno R3, as I have only worked with simulated ATMega on simulating software until now.

**I must mention I am not asking how to do this, not the programming or interfacing itself, I just want to ask more experienced users about the hardware limitations.**

Let me explain first what my project is, and then get to my questions.

I have to connect a couple of sensors to an Arduino, read their data, log them in a database, and use the database to show the received data on a website.

I can use Raspberry Pi SBCs to help in any part of the process if required. The number of sensors is not limited right now, I will also list all the hardware that is available at the end.

**My Questions are:**

1- How many sensors can an Arduino Uno R3 can handle at the same time?

2- If it can handle more than a couple,

3- or if it can handle one sensor at a time?

4- And also, is it better (or easier) to directly use an Arduino to log the data,

5- or pass it on to Raspberry Pi and use that to log the data on to the database

(and I assume I would have to use ADC Analog to Digital converters for this).

(I have to interface at least 3 or 4 of these sensors for the project to be accepted and approved)

The hardware I am working with is as follows :

- Arduino Uno R3
- Raspberry Pi Zero w
- Raspberry Pi 3b+
- Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB)
- DHT11 Module (temperature & humidity)
- PIR HC SR501
- MPS20N0040D (pressure)
- Water Level Sensor Module
- Rain Sensor YL-85
- LDR Sensor Module
- YL-100 Module (soil dampness)
- Flame Detection Module (4pin , similar to waveshare model)

P.S.: Please comment if any further information is needed, and thanks for your help.

Comment: Since this is your project, maybe it's you who should figure out what interfaces do these sensors have, and then assess how to connect multiple sensors if even possible or how, and then see how many sensors you end up with. I don't think many here would begin to google for the datasheets of each sensor and read how to connect them just to come up with a number for you. Limit is defined by hardware and software so it also depends if you need to code this yourself or are allowed to use the Arduino libraries which basically do all the work for you but may have limitations.

Comment: the main limit on Uno is the size of the flash memory and SRAM, not the speed or count of pins. but you can still switch to Arduino with larger ATmega MCU

Comment: @Justme as I already put the relative part in bold I did not ask on how. I said I would figure that part out, I mentioned the parts only as reference so People won't ask "what parts you will be using" later. as the libraries matter I don't think using them violate the terms because the more important part of the project is getting the data on the website , which has to be in realtime or at least with a couple of minutes of delay at worst. but lets keep the software part out of the question. my problem is that can I connect and use the said sensors at the same time? or I have to use extra means

Comment: @Justme like using multiplexers. what I meant was does the number of pins available on the device limit me on how many sensors I can connect simultaneously?

Comment: It is impossible to say with that info, because different sensors have different buses and can have different hardware limitations. It really needs more research. For example if those are ready made modules, the answer might be different that if you used bare chips and designed the hardware yourself. It really boils down to what modules you will use and how they are connected.

Comment: @justme right, I have to read some parts of their data sheet anyway, so if I find my answer through those then I will update the question accordingly, and if I don't get any answers from them but can provide more relevant information, I will comment here and inform you, thanks, btw as I bought these recently they are mostly ready made modules, and as far as the seller provided the information, most of them transfer their data digitally, I will get back to you on that.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino has a pair of pins for serial communications called "I2C" and this serial bus can handle up to 127 devices (possible 128 but I think address 0 is forbidden.  Anyhow, the trouble is, many devices have a pre-programmed number (address) inside.  The devices may have a few solder pads to change the address over a short range.  But, if you want a lot of the same sensor, you'll need to be sure you can get a version that has enough configurable addresses to meet your needs.  You don't need all 127 possible addresses, you just need enough.

If you don't want the super-simple two-wire serial bus (plus power and ground), you can look into SPI which Arduino also supports but requires 5-wires plus one wire per each additional device (or another way to address all of the devices because a "chip enable" pin is required for each device.

Another option is to use all the various ADCs on your Arduino if you want to go super simple but not all sensors offer an analog-output that you can connect to because I2c and SPI and other serial communication formats have really taken over the market.

A much easier answer would be possible if you just tell us how many you want.

Comment: First thanks for the thorough and also a not biased answer.

Comment: about how many I have to ask that to see what is the minimum that is required of me. how about using a couple of multiplexers? most of these sensors have between 3 pins to 5 pins, which there is 1 for GND and one for VCC most of the time which leaves 1 to 3 pins for data and other things. would using 3 "4 to 1" (or "8 to 1" for more sensors) multiplexers help? this way I could control these 3 MUXs to select an individual sensor and then read their data.